Using Python to do report automation
I am trying to create on a report automation tool where I can do the following things with python:

First import pictures, then have the ability to label each picture and send them to different sections based on their label(a, b, c) later. (My idea would be to create a folder to contain all the pictures and just make my script go thru the pics and let me choose the preset label)
Then the tool will send the pictures to ChatGPT with APIs to get some response/feedback, and it has the ability to ask Chatgpt to rewrite or just edit(delete, change, add) the text myself. (Already sorted out the Chatgpt API part)
After everything is good, gather the response/feedback text along with the picture and turn it into a PDF file. (Did some research and think Reportlab can do this)

I am kinda stuck on the part where the tool can let me edit the response/feedback chatgpt(step 2).  It would be great to get some help or idea on this tool, Thanks in advance!

Your project sounds interesting and quite comprehensive! For the part where you want to edit the response/feedback from ChatGPT before generating the PDF, you might want to look into using a combination of a text editor interface in your application.
By the way, if you find yourself frequently working with PDF reports and automation, there are tools out there like CxReports (disclaimer, my team is behind the app) that could streamline the process and save you some time. Just a thought based on my experience.
Good luck with your project! If you have more specific questions about the editing step, feel free to ask.
